# Perform different operations based on index modulus of list items

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, pandas, slice

For a given list, I wish to:

1. for the first element alone, and then every 3rd subsequent element (indices 3, 6 etc.), do nothing
2. starting with the second element (index 1) and then for every 3 elements (indices 4, 7 etc.), perform a certain operation
3. starting with the third element (index 2) and then for every 3 elements (indices 5, 8 etc.), perform yet a different operation

I can use combine `range(len(mylist))` and the `::` notation to slice the list in steps:

```
1::3 will give me the elements at indices 1, 4, 7, 10 etc.

::2 will give me the elements at indices 0, 2, 4, 6 etc.
```

But there's a few problems here:

- I don't need to access element 6, for example
- There is some overlap
  between the 2 slices
- Indices such as 5 are missing

Does Python provide an in-built mechanism for custom step-wise slicing?
FWIW, I am actually dealing with a pandas (version 0.18.0) Series, I have just used the example of a regular list for ease of explanation.

Comment: Why do you have ```::2```? ```2::3``` sounds more like what you are trying to achieve. Note that the slicing notation is ```start:end:step```

Comment: You would have explained better to others using an example of sample list, and desire output based on that list. And giving explanation based on the example

Comment: As per my understanding, you already know how list slicing works. I didn't understood the problem part that you mentioned.

Comment: @Lolgast yep `2::3` was the missing piece, thanks

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Indeed. Thanks for showing me that all I had to do was re-read what I was looking to achieve to see that I already had the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to make multiple passes through the data, or do any slicing:

```
def nop(x): return x

def op1(x): return x.upper()

def op2(x): return x[::-1]

data = 'One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine'.split()

result = [(nop, op1, op2)[i % 3](x) for i, x in enumerate(data)]
```

Which produces the following `result`:

```
['One', 'TWO', 'eerhT', 'Four', 'FIVE', 'xiS', 'Seven', 'EIGHT', 'eniN']
```

In case it isn't clear, what's happening here is that the (i%3)th element of `(nop, op1, op2)` is called with `x` as an argument, for each index `i` and element `x` in the enumeration of `data`.

Obviously if you need to do things *to* `data` rather than return a new list, you can do so in a regular `for` loop:

```
for i, x in enumerate(data):
    data[i] = (nop, op1, op2)[i % 3](x)
```

Comment: I am familiar with list comprehension and `enumerate()`, but had not seen this sort of notation `(nop, op1, op2)[i % 3](x)` before. What's this called?

Comment: @Pyderman the technique is known as "caller dispatch", or more often "dict dispatch" (because a dict tends to be used rather than a tuple in many of the circumstances where it's useful). Here's a post about it: [Why store a function inside a python dictionary?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182093/why-store-a-function-inside-a-python-dictionary) It's not really a special notation, just a mildly unusual combination of indexing and calling syntax.